# Particles rotate unwillingly on a surface along normals using Particles hair

Tags: animation, particles, hair

here is my problem I am stuck now for some hours.
I want to create a sphere whose surface is filled with objects. However when I animate the sphere and rotate it, the particles rotate unwillingly along the normals of the sphere during rotation.
My goal is to get these particles stay put on the surface as if the grow out of it. They should simply move with the surface.
[image]

I use particles hair. What ever I do, like setting rotation along the normals i.e., the objects rotate on their own. However it seems like the objects that are on the X/Y-Axis behave correctly.

What am I missing here?

thank you.

Project file:
[image]

Comment: is Physics enabled for the particles?

Comment: Convert particle system to mesh if not too many objects are put on the surface.

Comment: @bruno yes Physics are enabled. If I disable it all particles disappear.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth my example is just a breakdown of a bigger scene where I have this problem. Therefore convertig to mesh was not an option. However I will give it a try  to see what happens. thnx


Addition: i tried it. Yes this works. However I thought it should work without it. especially when it comes to more particles and an more advanced setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Emitter` instead of `Hair`

- Check `Rotation`/`Normal` to align the particles to the Face normals
- Disable `Physics`
- Check `Unborn` and `Dead` to make sure the particles don't appear/disappear

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. This solved my problem.  I didn't know I could hold the particles like that. You made my day :D

Comment: Good, glad it helped. I didn't find a way to make it work with Hair type particles...

Comment: Yes, me either. Most of the tutorials about this are just for still images. So it is difficult to find this special case. thank you again